# Deleting object from parse-server code causing error?

Tags: swift, parse-server

I am developing an app in Xcode using swift and am using a heroku-hosted parse-server as my database. I want to be able to delete an object from the database, but I keep getting an error when trying to type out the code. Here is what I have:

```
{
        let removingObjectQuery = PFQuery(className: "GoingTo")
        removingObjectQuery.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: goingToSelectionID)
        removingObjectQuery.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (object, error) in
            if let objects = object{
                print("Object found")
                for object in objects{
                        object.deleteInBackground()  
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

But the delete `.deleteInBackground` keeps sending an error to in the code line saying that ".deleteInBackground is not a member of [PFObject]"... except that I thought it *is* a member of that value type?

Edit: Syntax fixed to allow calling of `.deleteInBackground` but now am receiving error in logs (which does not crash the app) that "[Error]: Object not found". The object is for sure in the DB and whereKey `equalTo:` is adequately described... (goingToSelectionID is indeed the objectId in the DB... checked this by printing to logs). Not sure what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The findObjectsInBackground method doesn't return results of type PFObject, but [PFObject], which is an array of PFObjects... If you want to delete the whole array, you can use the class method deleteAllInBackground like so:

```
PFObject.deleteAllInBackground(objectt, block: nil)
```

Or you can iterate through the array:

```
for objectt in object! {
    objectt.deleteInBackground()
}
```

Comment: I edited to the question with the fixed syntax. The call works, but now I am receiving another error... telling me that the object is not found (despite the variable in the whereKey that is `equalTo:` for sure matching the `objectId` in the DB). Any ideas?

Comment: So, none of the objects in the array were deleted?

Comment: No, I have posted another question regarding the issue (because it is related but asking a different question) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39844324/why-does-user-not-have-permission-to-delete-object-in-parse-server-db-despite-ha